# Open camera roll on the latest photo

Tags: ios, ios6

I know already how to open the camera roll:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[picker setDelegate:self];

[picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[picker setAllowsEditing:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

But I want it to go directly to the latest picture. It does it when you use the iPhone original camera. When you click on the thumbnail of the taken photo, the camera roll open and display it directly.

Is it possible to do this way?

Comment: Is this one not working for you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200553/how-to-retrieve-the-most-recent-photo-from-camera-roll-on-ios

Comment: I have the latest photo as my app created it :) I just want to let the user see it from the camera roll