# Launch photo library without using uiimagepicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios10

I am working on a camera app. I need to adapt the same behavior of the default camera app which opens camera roll when you tap the image on the left corner.

How I can launch camera roll as the default app does? I do not want to get an image, so I don't need to use the UIImagePickerController

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172251/open-a-saved-image-in-camera-roll-programmatically-ios?rq=1) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824535/open-camera-roll-on-the-latest-photo) question. Seems like it is not possible, unless you make your own custom implementation of a gallery.

Comment: Do you want to take an image from camera?

Comment: Both above questions are 3 and 4 years before, so it may be a newer way :)

Comment: @Adeel No I do not need to take an image, just to view the photo library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Photos Framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos)** Available from iOS 8.Using this framework,you will get direct access to photos.You can build your own image editing apps using this Framework.

Please download the sample code from this link :
[Photos framework sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response but it does not mimic the default photo library

Comment: It will give access to images but you need to create the UI.If you are looking for something like this Link,
https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker
you can either use this library you can build it using the Above said Photo Library.
Anyway to build a view like this you need to use Photo framework.

Comment: A powerful factor that I will accept the answer is due to the wonderful library that you shared. Also yes you answer it with poor expressions though but anyway thanks for the help.