# How to copy ALL photos from one photo album my app's document folder on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, alassetslibrary

I want to access and copy all the photos from one album in my iPhone photo album to my app's document folder AUTOMATICALLY WHEN THE APP STARTS.

There are a lot of questions/answers on here on using the UIImagePicker. I know I can do it with the image picker and have the user select the photos but I would really like it if I could do it without the user selecting the photos.

I have used the following question/answer to help with the code below: [How to retrieve the most recent photo from Camera Roll on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200553/how-to-retrieve-the-most-recent-photo-from-camera-roll-on-ios?answertab=active#tab-top)

I was able to successfully save the one image in my documents folder but cannot figure out how to save more than one at a time.

```
     ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes: ALAssetsGroupAlbum  //ALAssetsGroupAlbum before I CHANGED it
                             usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)  { //
                                 if (nil != group) {
                                     // be sure to filter the group so you only get photos
                                     [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];

                                     [group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: group.numberOfAssets - 1 ]// -1
                                                            options:0
                                                         usingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {


                                                        if (nil != result)
                                                              {
                                                                ALAssetRepresentation *repr = [result defaultRepresentation];
                                                                  // this is the most recent saved photo
                                                                  UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[repr fullResolutionImage]];
                                                                  // we only need the first (most recent) photo -- stop the enumeration
                                                                  // *stop = YES;

                                                                  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                                                                  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

                                                                  int num = 1;
                                                                  NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%d.png",@"boxOneImage", num]];
                                                                  num++;

                                                                  NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
                                                                  [data writeToFile:path atomically: YES];



                                                              }
                                                          }];
                                 }

                                 *stop = NO;
                             } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                 NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
                             }];
```

UPDATE: I was able to figure it out and load images from just an album not the camera roll to my app documents folder using the following code:

```
    __block int num = 1;

ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
{
    if (nil != group)
    {
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];

        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){

            if (nil != result)
            {
                ALAssetRepresentation *repr = [result defaultRepresentation];
                // this is the most recent saved photo
                UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[repr fullResolutionImage]];

                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


                NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%d.png",@"boxOneImage", num]];
                num++;

                NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
                [data writeToFile:path atomically: YES];

            }
        }];
    }

    *stop = NO;
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}];
```

If anyone has or knows a better way of doing this, then please share. I would love to see it and learn from it. Thanks!!!

Comment: refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633843/get-all-of-the-pictures-from-an-iphone-photolibrary-in-an-array-using-assetslibr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your existing method itself will work with a small change.

Remove `int num = 1;` which is in the block and add `__block int num = 1;` outside the block, may be before `assetsLibrary` initialisation.

Or a much better solution, remove variable `num` completely, make use of `index+1` passed to the block!

Comment: Thanks it worked but this only allowed me to get the last two photosusing this code: [group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: group.numberOfAssets - 1 ]. How can I change this code or the whole thing in general to take all images of an album or a set number? Would love to see some sample code if possible...thanks

Comment: UPDATE: I used the following code: `[group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, group.numberOfAssets - 1)]` This allowed me to get all the photos in my camera roll but I would like to get all the images in an album of mine I created.