# Is it possible to use the CameraRoll API of Adobe Air to load an image without browseForImage?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm using Adobe Air for an iOS8 app and I would like to load the latest added image of the Photos app.
I was thinking about using the [CameraRoll](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/CameraRoll.html) API but would that work without a direct user interaction through *browseForImage*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to receive the last photo with the help of a native code:
[How to retrieve the most recent photo from Camera Roll on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200553/how-to-retrieve-the-most-recent-photo-from-camera-roll-on-ios) .

You can write Adobe Native Extansion(ANE) to transfer the last photo from a native code to ActionScript.
Instructions for creating ANE:
http://gamespoweredby.com/blog/2014/12/developing-adobe-air-native-extensions-for-ios-tutorial-1-en/

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this using UIKit in a native iOS app, but AIR doesn't provide a method to select items from the camera roll without user interaction.