# How to get screenshot image

Tags: ios, screenshot

Observing `UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification` notification can notify users if they have taken a screenshot pressing home button + power button.The question is how can I fetch the newly screenshot image?

```
// observe screenshot notification
NSOperationQueue *mainQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification
          object:nil
           queue:mainQueue
      usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

         // How to get screenshot image?
      }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this to get the recent image:

```
    // How to get screenshot image?
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
                                 usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
                                     if (nil != group) {
                                         // be sure to filter the group so you only get photos
                                         [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];

                                         if (group.numberOfAssets > 0) {
                                             [group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:group.numberOfAssets - 1]
                                                                     options:0
                                                                  usingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
                                                                      if (nil != result) {
                                                                          ALAssetRepresentation *repr = [result defaultRepresentation];
                                                                          // this is the most recent saved photo
                                                                          UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[repr fullResolutionImage]];
                                                                          // we only need the first (most recent) photo -- stop the enumeration
                                                                          *stop = YES;
                                                                      }
                                                                  }];
                                         }
                                     }

                                     *stop = NO;
                                 } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                     NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
                                 }];
```

Ref: [How to retrieve the most recent photo from Camera Roll on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200553/how-to-retrieve-the-most-recent-photo-from-camera-roll-on-ios)

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: But the user must accept Camera Roll permission !! I suggest to take again a screenshot, but programmatically at same time, in your observer. That way you have a copy of user screenshot, without asking permission.