# Setting an image viewer to a picture stored in the camera roll of an iPhone

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to figure out how to populate an image viewer with an image stored on the camera roll of an iPhone.  I was thinking of using the following code:

```
   @IBOutlet weak var imageoutlet: UIImageView!  //remove the weak
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageoutlet.image = UIImage(named:"IMG_0031.JPG")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

As a way to populate the image viewer object (called imageoutlet) with an image named "IMG_0031.JPG").  I tried doing it this way but unfortunately it did not work.  If someone can give me advice on a good way to access and populate images stored on an iPhone's Camera roll, I will be very grateful.  Thanks!

Comment: do you want to find specific image or all images from Camera roll?

Comment: Either would be good at this point.  Preferably a specific image

Comment: to find the specific, how can you select the params?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10200857/2963912

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve the most recent photo from Camera Roll on iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200553/how-to-retrieve-the-most-recent-photo-from-camera-roll-on-ios)

Comment: Thanks, these are both fairly useful.  Where exactly should I put this?

Comment: in viewDidLoad and use background thread to populate the array