# iOS: Get last image from the camera roll

Tags: ios, image, camera-roll

I want the last image saved in camera roll.
I have searched for it but m getting result for ALAssetsLibrary which is deprecated in iOS 9 so please provide me solution for this because m not getting proper solution for that.

I want solution in objective C.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867496/get-last-image-from-photos-app

Comment: i have checked that it gives errors

Comment: may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200553/how-to-retrieve-the-most-recent-photo-from-camera-roll-on-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this code... it may help you.

```
PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];
PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:fetchOptions];
PHAsset *lastAsset = [fetchResult lastObject];
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:lastAsset
                                          targetSize:self.photoLibraryButton.bounds.size
                                         contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                             options:PHImageRequestOptionsVersionCurrent
                                       resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {

                                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                               [[self photoLibraryButton] setImage:result forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                                           });
                                       }];
```

Comment: ALAssetsLibrary is deprecated in ios 9

Comment: She mentioned **ALAssetsLibrary which is deprecated in iOS 9**

Comment: ALAssetsLibrary was deprecated in iOS 8 and replaced with PHPhotoLibrary ;)

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 8, Apple added the Photos library which makes for easier querying.

```
import UIKit
import Photos

struct LastPhotoRetriever {
    func queryLastPhoto(resizeTo size: CGSize?, queryCallback: (UIImage? -> Void)) {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

//        fetchOptions.fetchLimit = 1 // This is available in iOS 9.

        if let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(PHAssetMediaType.Image, options: fetchOptions) {
            if let asset = fetchResult.firstObject as? PHAsset {
                let manager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()

                // If you already know how you want to resize, 
                // great, otherwise, use full-size.
                let targetSize = size == nil ? CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth, height: asset.pixelHeight) : size!

                // I arbitrarily chose AspectFit here. AspectFill is 
                // also available.
                manager.requestImageForAsset(asset,
                    targetSize: targetSize,
                    contentMode: .AspectFit,
                    options: nil,
                    resultHandler: { image, info in

                    queryCallback(image)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how i set it? example i have self.myImageView.image =  ????? (don't understand), thanks in advance

Comment: @JirsonTavera You have to set image received to your imageView in `queryCallback` closure.